# I cannot retrieve locale strings in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

For somewhat reason Laravel won't return the string but simply the key:

Here is my messages.php saved in /resources/lang/en/

```
return[
    'Example' => 'Ejemplo',
    'Otroejemplo' => 'Beispiel',
];
```

This is my routing:

```
Route::get('myexample/{locale}', function ($locale)  {
    App::setLocale($locale);
    return view('admin.pages.forms.myexample');
});
```

And this is myexample.blade.php:

```
@lang('messages.Example');
```

I expect to get Ejemplo in return when I open localhost:8000/myexample/en but I get message.Example instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tested your code, it's working fine the only issue I got is instead of

```
   Route::get('myexample/{locale}', function ($locale)  {
    App::setLocale($locale);
    return view('admin.pages.forms.myexample');
});
```

use

```
Route::get('myexample/{locale}', function ($locale)  {
    App::setLocale($locale);
    return view('myexample'); // in case your view is in resources folder
});
```

Comment: I was actually opening localhost:8000/myexample/es instead of /en. I noticed after you told me my code was working. The code itself is fine so I am deleting the question.